# WebClient vs. Proxy Settings - or fun with Download Accelerators

Tags: .net, proxy, webclient

I have a relatively simple feature that uses the WebClient class to perform 
an HTTPS POST to a web server.  This code works reliably but encounters 
problems when using the EarthLink or AT&T download accelerator feature.

The download accelerator works by changing the dial-up connection's proxy 
settings to specify localhost:8080 for the HTTP protocol only. In this 
configuration, presumably the HTTPS protocol should be unaffected.  In fact, 
when using Internet Explorer to navigate to https://www.wellsfargo.com, there 
is no error.

However, when using .NET 2.0 (or 3.5), the WebClient class fails to perform 
a simple HTTPS GET from https://www.wellsfargo.com in this configuration.

As a simple test, I do the following:

Specify an advanced LAN proxy configuration where:

HTTP address: **whacked:8080**

Secure address: **securewhacked:8081**

In, C# I call the following functions:

```
IWebProxy defaultWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
Uri proxyUri = defaultWebProxy.GetProxy("https://www.wellsfargo.com");
```

I would expect that proxyUri should be "securewhacked:8081".

Instead, proxyUri is "whacked:8080".

This seems like a bug in the .NET "automatic" proxy usage.  And the result 
is that our software fails when the download accelerator is turned on.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

I know that it's relatively easy for customers to disable the accelerator, 
but I would rather our software work out of the box without requiring the 
user to disable the accelerator.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the accelerator set on the user's (IE) proxy setting, the machines (WinHTTP) proxy setting, or both? If IE, you might like to try using `proxycfg -u` to import the IE settings into WinHTTP (since I believe this is what `WebClient` (and .NET generally) uses).